# How to Customize the time interval of long/delay button pressed in android

Tags: android

I am making an app's which have a button to performed an action, but i want to perform the action when user long press on the button.Since Google provides the long press time duration appx .5 sec but I want to customize this time duration. Please help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `Touch Listener` to do this.

Try:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handler.postDelayed(run, 5000/* OR the amount of time you want */);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Where `b` is the `view` on which you want to make long click.

And `Runnable` `run` is as follows

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code to run on long click

    }
};
```

Hope it helps... :)

Comment: It is working fine on emulator but not on mobile device. Please help me

Comment: I have edited my answer. Changed `ACTION_MOVE` to `ACTION_CANCEL`.

Comment: Handlers and postDelayed are more commonly used on android that Timers, mostly because they allow to execute code on the UI thread, which is often what you would want to do in a long press listener

Comment: @njzk2: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my anwser, is it right now?

Comment: yep, looks good (also, the timer approach is perfectly valid as long as you don't need to act on the ui)

Comment: Simply the best