# OnTouchListener Delay not functioning

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I cannot for the life of me find any help online to describe to me why the delay for the "ACTION_DOWN" is not functional.  The rest of my code executes as soon as I touch the image.  My intent is placed between the //additional code and //end additional code comments.  Does it need to be placed elsewhere?  Thanks in advance!

Edit:  I would use an onLongClickListener but my intention is to extend the time the object has to be held in order for the intent to begin.

```
mImage = (ImageView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.Floaterimg);
    mImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        final Handler handler2 = new Handler(); 
        Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                Log.i("", "Long press!");

            }
        };
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    handler2.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 3000);

                                    //additional code
                                    //end of additional code

                if((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)||
(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP))
                    handler2.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                    return false;    
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you thinked about the ACTION_MOVE is executed before the 3000 milliseconds and it removes the callback?

Comment: How do I resolve this problem?  Bear with me, I have only been dabbling in android dev for a week or so.
I took your comment to mean that I may be moving my finger unintentionally, so i removed MotionEven.ACTION_MOVE, but to the same effect.

Comment: Try to remove `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` on the second condition and check if the Runnable is executed.

Comment: I still have the exact same problem as in the question.  check the edited comment.  Thank you for your patience.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use mImage.setOnLongClickListener()?

Comment: Because, as far as I understand, you can not change the time required for pressing down on the object before starting the intent with OnLongClickListener.  If you can that would be an excellent solution.

Comment: Here is working, the difference I can see with your code is that you are returning false on the second if, and you are checking for ACTION_MOVE instead ACTION_CANCEL. Another difference is that your runnable is inside the actionListener. Hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393530/how-to-customize-the-time-interval-of-long-delay-button-pressed-in-android

Comment: I looked over the answer posted there.  Where should the runnable go if not inside the actionListener?

Comment: Your suggestion helped me to fix my problem, but arose another bug.  Perhaps you could shed some light on this idea for me, as well?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436127/action-up-action-cancel-not-operating-correction-in-ontouch-listener

Answer (score 1):

use setOnLongClickListener instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: Because, as far as I understand, you can not change the time required for pressing down on the object before starting the intent with OnLongClickListener.  If you can that would be an excellent solution.

Comment: see here how they implemented GestureDetector https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java, you can just copy that and modify the long press tout